# Finding two masses as one rotates about an axis, no givens

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, rotational-kinematics, rotation

My Physics C class was given a lab today with little explanation, and many of us are having issues determining a solution.

We are given this apparatus:
[image]

We must find the masses of both objects m and M. We aren't allowed spring scales, springs, or scales. Using cameras, timers, and rulers, we must find the masses.

I've attempted to derive multiple equations for each mass with the kinematic equations, rotational kinematic equations, and energy equations, however when I use them in a system of equations, the masses always cancel out.

My next idea is to determine rotational momentum, convert the rotational momentum to linear momentum, and take the derivative to find force. I'm not really sure what force this is, but if I got that far I believe I could figure it out.

Another issue is that the masses aren't uniform, and are in the shape of a conical frustrum:[image]

What am I missing? This seems like an odd problem or a trick question. Our physics teacher is known to throw stuff at us like this without a prepared solution, so I'm worried this is one of those times.

Thank you!

Comment: *I've attempted to derive multiple equations for each mass with the kinematic equations, rotational kinematic equations, and energy equations, however when I use them in a system of equations, the masses always cancel out.* No one can say if you are doing anything wrong here if you don't show what you are trying to do and which physics concepts are tripping you up. Using N2L you should easily be able to at least determine the ratio $m/M$

Comment: @AaronStevens the free-body diagram for this system doesn't provide any useful information. The bottom mass's net force is zero because the only two forces acting on it are gravity and tension. The top mass's net force cannot be found because the horizontal component of its net force is tension which includes mass, which is unknown

Comment: I am just trying to help. I think it is a great problem, but typically questions like these are closed as being off-topic for this specific site. Usually a question is better received here where work is shown and the focus is on a specific physics concept.

Comment: I think all you can do here is determine $m/M$, but I will not post an answer saying this since I don't have a somewhat rigorous proof of it. And perhaps I am just not being creative enough about it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE!Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.